# How in XPages CSJS should I select a ComboBox value?

Tags: javascript, combobox, xpages

I am using CSJS in the 'onChange' Event in a ComboBox, and when a user selects a value, I want an EditBox and a second ComboBox to be set (The second ComboBox value is one that is already in the list, I just want to select it).

To set the EditBox in my 'onChange' Event I used:

```
XSP.getElementById("#{id:fldEditBox}").value = newEditBoxValue;
```

But selecting a value in the ComboBox was much harder.  At first I used the EditBox method:

```
XSP.getElementById("#{id:fldComboBox2}").value = selectedComboBoxValue;
```

The on screen value changed, and the ComboBox functioned normally, when the document was saved it still had the old value.

I tried all sorts of things like selectedIndex but nothing worked.  Eventually I found that this:

```
document.getElementsByName("#{id:fldComboBox2}")[0].value = selectedComboBoxValue;
```

meant the change was saved, but was not visible on screen, so in my final production code I used both and it works:

```
XSP.getElementById("#{id:fldComboBox2}").value = selectedComboBoxValue;
document.getElementsByName("#{id:fldComboBox2}")[0].value = selectedComboBoxValue;
```

This seems ugly to me, there must be a better way of doing this in CSJS, does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you set the value of a select element (combobox) in vanilla JavaScript is to loop through the elements `options` property to find the option you want to select:

```
var comboBox = document.getElementById("#{id:comboBox}");
for (var i=0; i < comboBox.options.length; i++) {
  if (comboBox.options[i].value == "ValueYouWantSelected") {
    comboBox.options.selectedIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

If you have JQuery available you can do it more elegantly:

```
var xpageID = "#{id:comboBox}".replace(/:/gi, "\\:");
var valueYouWantSelected = "someValue";
$('#' + xpageID + ' option[value="' + valueYouWantSelected + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

The xpageID variable is there because you have to escape the ':' characters that XPages puts in the generated IDs for it to work with the JQuery selector engine.

Comment: if i use the vanilla JavaScript above, using either document.getElementById or XSP.getElementById all I get is 'comboBox.options is undefined.

Comment: Is XSP/document.getElementById returning undefined or in other words is comboBox variable undefined? Also check the rendered HTML - are there any <option> elements in the <select> element that represents your combobox?

Comment: No, its the options that is undefined.  The HMTL for the target field is: `<select id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:quoteDynamicContent:fldComboBox2" name="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:quoteDynamicContent:fldComboBox2" class="xspComboBox" size="1" style="width:90%" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" aria-required="true"> <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
 <option value="Low" selected="selected">Low</option>
 <option value="Exempt">Exempt</option>
 <option value="Out of Scope">Out of Scope</option>
</select>`

Comment: It's because you are using `dojoType="dijit.Form.FilteringSelect"`. Dojo is transforming the markup after the page loads so you can't treat this like a normal select. You have to use `dijit.byId('theId')` to get an handle on it and then call `handle.get('value')` to get the selected value and `handle.set('value','yourValue')` to set it.